# Acceptable memory size consumed by mobile game in 2017?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, mobile, cocos2d-x-js

How do you think, what is the acceptable memory size consumed by mobile game in 2017, taking into account current state of mobile devices hardware performance?
I've made a pack of optimizations using a number of recommendations and managed to reduce memory consumption from 270Mb to 120Mb, but it still seems to me too much.
Anyway, my game looks pretty nice, smooth and fast on iPhone 5s (produced in 2013), also I run it on cheapest no-name android, and it still looks quite good.
So my question can be rephrased this way: is there anything criminal if the game eats about 200Mb of RAM in our reality when 1Gb of ram is not something incredible for the mobile device?

Comment: This depends on the requirements of your game. The ideal is to make the memory consumption as low as possible without sacrificing your desired quality level.

Comment: In 2017, what's acceptable is ~512 MB. Beyond "acceptable", less is obviously better, because that way your application also works on cheaper devices. Always keep in mind what you actually want to achieve. "Uses less memory" is not an end goal. "Runs on 90% of devices sold in 2013 in <geographical area>" is an end goal.